# Find out which VScode extentions are slowing the IDE down

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I am finding that VScode is a lot slower than normal and I think one of the many extensions I have installed is slowing it down.
to fix this I tried to find out how much each extention was slowing down the program but i couldn't find a way to do it and so I was wondering if anybody else had found a way

**TLDR**: How to find out the resources used by my installed VScode extensions

Comment: it depends on what you do at the moment, an extension can use a lot of time to determine Hovers, QuickFix, GotoDef,..... You can use the `Extension Bisect` to find the slow extension

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the `Developer: Show Running Extensions` option inside of the Command Palette (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>) you can see extension load times.

Comment: I was able to track the culprit extension using the "Host Profile" feature of that Window.  Disabled it and now VS Code is once again fast! 

Comment: This will only help you find extensions with a long startup time. If there are certain extensions that slow down VS Code during regular interactions such as saving a file, there is no chance to find them via `Developer: Show Running Extensions`.

Comment: my vscode is running so slow it took over 3 mins to load the Running Extensions page

Answer (score 1):

In combination with the initial startup time answer from @Daan Breur, I'm using `htop` to see them also during runtime.
If you scroll to the right, you gonna see something like

`Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --type=utility --utility-sub-type=node.mojom.NodeService --lang=en-GB --service-sandbox-type=none --dns-result-order=ipv4firs`

`.../MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node --experimental-modules ../.vscode/extensions/svelte.svelte-vscode-107.12.0/node_modules/svelte-language-server/bin/server.js --node-ipc --clientProcessId=92690`

or

`.../.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.3.20231014/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js`

which seems in my case typescript and svelte extentions

Comment: Helpull thanks!

On my end it's your first example that pops up with 99% CPU usage. How to know which extension is creating this? It just says code helper (Plugin) ... Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I experience the sluggish behavior at `paste` operations after I switched the extension `Spell Right` on.

I had all extension swtiched off for a while without experiencing any delays and then switched `Spell Right` back on because I needed it and - bingo - the delay was here again!

Version: 1.87.1
Commit: 1e790d77f81672c49be070e04474901747115651
Date: 2024-03-06T00:21:07.287Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.1.0-18-amd64